# Delay in typing Text

Tags: android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have webview in my android (4.0.0) app where in I have a text field . 
When I'm trying to type "Korean" text in field it gets delay of 3 seconds, then it print a letter Or I press spacebar it print letter immediately.
 
Please suggest me what could be reason behind this behavior. Whereas it works fine when I run my app in android greater than 4.0.

Comment: It was because of css -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; added for the field

Comment: set HardwareAccelration:true in andorid manifest